# create schema without application restart in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring

I am implementing multi-tenancy in my application..switching between database is working fine, but here challenge is I want to create a new schema whenever user is registering to my application. Without application restart is it possible to create new schema programmatically ?

After research I got to know that using stored-procedure we can achieve this..but I wanted to know is there any better approach where we can create schema without application restart..

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but you can try same thing using Flyway integration when you get this kind of request from URL create SQL configuration file based on requirement and run it using flyway object.

Comment: You can execute any SQL with JDBC. Also create schemas